# gmock ignore "interesting" function call

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googlemock

I want to use gmock in my unit tests. I wrote very simple example and it fails. ISymbolTable is interface I want to mock. MockSymbolTable is mocked object. In test I call insert and check if any insert was called.

GMOCK WARNING:

> Uninteresting mock function call - returning directly. Function call:
>   insert(8-byte object <24-7C 4C-04 03-00 00-00>) Stack trace:
>   LexerTests.cpp:25: Failure Actual function call count doesn't match
>   EXPECT_CALL(symbolTable, insert(::testing::_))...

```
class ISymbolTable {
 public:
  ISymbolTable() {}
  virtual ~ISymbolTable() {};
  virtual void insert(const Entry entry) = 0;
  virtual int lookUp(const std::string text) = 0;
};

class MockSymbolTable : public ISymbolTable {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD1(insert, void(const Entry entry));
  MOCK_METHOD1(lookUp, int(const std::string text));
};

TEST(Lexer, N) {
  MockSymbolTable symbolTable;
  symbolTable.insert(Entry("dsgft", 3));
  EXPECT_CALL(symbolTable, insert(::testing::_)).Times(1);
}
```

Comment: unrelated, you should pass arguments by const reference (`const &`) not const value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to rewrite the test case as follows

```
TEST(Lexer, N) {
  MockSymbolTable symbolTable;
  EXPECT_CALL(symbolTable, insert(::testing::_)).Times(1);

  symbolTable.insert(Entry("dsgft", 3));
}
```

All call expectations must be set up before the mock object is touched first.

Comment: You modified my question's title. I think test should pass and this is my problem. I don't want to hide this warning.

Comment: @EmilJasiński Sorry about that. Your question was a bit unclear for me. I've spotted what your problem is/was. Edited my answer.